# Why don't Zeilberger and Gosper's algorithms contradict Richardson's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, lo.logic, computability-theory, hypergeometric-functions, decidability

Richardson's theorem proves that whether an expression A is equal to zero is undecidable. A is in this case an expression, constructed from $x,e^x,\sin(x)$ and the constant function $\pi$ and $\ln(2)$ as well as all integers. Further, various operators are allowed (for a comprehensive list see the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem)).

Zeilberger, Gosper, Knuth and many others worked on algorithms for finding hypergeometric identities ("A=B" by  Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf and Doron Zeilberger gives an overview). And, for a given set of hypergeometric functions, there are algorithms that can determine whether a sum of a subset is an identity. Since $x$, $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ are all hypergeometric functions, as well as any constant function and the operators yield hypergeometric functions as well (for example, for $a,b$ hypergeometric, $ab$ is hypergeometric as well), why don't these two discoveries contradict each other?

Comment: Do the hypergeometric identities algorithms allow for arbitrary composition of the functions?

Comment: Shouldn't the composition of two hypergeometic functions be hypergeometric?

Comment: There's your answer.

Comment: While I do have familiarity with the MRDP theorem, the resolution of Hilbert's 10th problem, and the connection with Richardson's theorem, I am less familiar with the hypergeometric identities, and I would appreciate it if someone could post an answer that resolved and summarized the central differences here.

Comment: It's as simple as "the composition of hypergeometric functions is not hypergeometric". $f(n)=2^n$ is a hypergeometric function because $f(n+1)/f(n)=2$ is a rational function of $n$, but $g(n)=(f\circ f)(n)=2^{2^n}$ satisfies $g(n+1)/g(n)=2^{2^n}$ which obviously grows much too fast to be rational.

Comment: Ah, that's what I had suspected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Comment turned into an answer:)
It's as simple as "the composition of hypergeometric terms is not hypergeometric". $f(n)=2^n$ is a hypergeometric term because $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=2$ is a rational term, but if we take $g(n)=\left(f\circ f\right)(n)=2^{2^n}$, then $\frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}=2^{2^n}$ grows much too quickly to be a rational term. (Indeed, I'd say that one of the great frustrations with W-Z and similar tools is how many nice looking functions they *don't* apply to...)

Comment: Ah, but $2^{2^n}$ **is** a hypergeometric function, right? I guess, I confused hypergeometric function (nearly every function used in standard mathematics) and hypergeometric term ($\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ is rational)

Comment: @MartinClever What definition of hypergeometric function are you using?

Comment: This one from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function